# Algorithm to find outliers of DateTimes outside of a 2 day window

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of arbitrary DateTime values that are input by users. The requirement is that the values are to be within a certain window, e.g. no more than 2 days apart from each other. There is no reference value to work from.

An unknown, but small percentage (say < 5%) of them will be outside the 2 day window because of user error. At some point, the values are aggregated and processed, at which point the requirement is checked. Validation at input time is not practical. How do I determine the largest set of values that fulfill the requirement, so that I can report back the other, incorrect values that don't fulfill the requirement?

I know about determining Interquartile Range. Can I somehow modify that algorithm to include the boundary condition? Or do I need a different algorithm?

Comment: Just speculation: Could you perhaps calculate the average day number for all the entries? - that would then be the middle of the 2-day interval. And after that eliminate those entries that are more than 24 hours away from that central reference point? Eliminated outliers would still influence the middle point. If this is a problem you could eliminate the most extreme values first and recalculate after each elimination. This would be slower, of course ...

Answer (score 0):

One good "quick strike" solution from Machine Learning is the support vector machine (SVM).  A 1-class method will be relatively fast, and will identify clustered values vs outliers with very good accuracy for this application.  Otherwise ...

You do *not* want the mean of the dates: a single error could skew the mean right out of the rest of the distribution, such as today's date being 20 Aug 2109.

The *median* is likely a good starting guess for this distribution.  Sort the values, grab the median, and then examine the distribution on either side.  At roughly 24 hours each way, there should be a sudden difference in values.  Those difference points will absolutely identify your proper boundaries.

In most data sets, you'll be able to find that point easily: look at the differences between adjacent values in your sorted list of dates.

Very simply:

- Sort the list of dates
- Make a new list, shifting one element left (i.e. delete the first element)
- Subtract the two lists.
- Move through the difference list; there will be a large cluster of small values in the middle, bounded by a pair of large jumps.  The pair of large jumps will be 48 hours apart.  Those points are you boundaries.